# How do you delete from csv table based on deletion from datagridview?

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, datagridview

I have a datagrid that stores its data to a csv file when the application closes and retrieves it on load. I have a button that deletes rows from the datagrid using the code shown below. When I call the delete method, the row deletes from the datagrid, but not from the csv file. This means that when I restart the application, the data is loaded back into the datagrid, but is not given the correct index and throws this error:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.Value.get returned null.`

How could I modify my delete statement so that it deletes both the row in the datagrid view, and delete the specific row from my csv file, so that it isn't displayed when I reload the application?

```
    private void DeleteItem()
    {
        var dataGrid = dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles;
        foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGrid.SelectedCells)
        {
            if (oneCell.Selected)
            {
                dataGrid.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
                GetSumOfCost();
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the code that stores the data:

```
    public void Store(MainForm form)
    {
        var data = form.dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles;

        using (var temp = new FileStream(@"C:\temp\Data.csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
        {

            TextWriter write = new StreamWriter(temp);
            for (int rows = 0; rows < data.Rows.Count; rows++)
            {
                for (int columns = 0; columns < data.Columns.Count; columns++)
                {
                    write.Write("\t" + data.Rows[rows].Cells[columns].Value.ToString() + "\t" + "|");
                }
                write.WriteLine("");
            }
            write.Close();
        }

    }
```

And here is the code that retrieves the data:

```
 public void Load(MainForm form)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\temp\Data.csv");
        string[] data;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            data = lines[i].ToString().Split('|');

            string[] row = new string[data.Length];

            for (int j = 0; j < data.Length; j++)
            {
                row[j] = data[j].Trim();
            }
            form.dataGridViewRegisteredVehicles.Rows.Add(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, It doesnt update the data from the table properly if you use that method

Comment: It looks like you "quote" a field using tab and separate by pipe, when you write. You don't do the same when you read. This will cause excess whitespace every time you read/write cycle

Answer (score 0):

Easier if you forget the CSV and use an XML file instead:

- Make a new form
- Put a datagridview on your form
- Put this code in the FormClosing event (double click FormClosing in the formdesigner, in the lightning bolt of the properties grid after clicking the background of the form)

```
    (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).WriteXml("grid.xml");
```

- Put this code in the FormLoad event:

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    if(File.Exists("grid.xml")){
      dt.ReadXml("grid.xml");
    } else {
      dt.Columns.Add("Name");
      dt.Columns.Add("Age");
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

So when you delete a row from the grid it will delete from the datatable. Being gone from the datatable means it isn't written to the file. The next time the program opens, the row is not present

This leverages the built in ability for a datatable to write itself/read itself from an xml file. If you want to extend it to doing a csv instead, you can merge in your existing code